# How to prevent page scrolling by jQuery animate function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that scrolls across multiple screens using jQuery's animate function.  I am using tab indeces set by jQuery for the form.  The problem is that when I give focus to the first element of the form using

```
$('#myforminput1').focus();
```

the page automatically scrolls to the element that has focus, even though it is on the third screen.  I don't want the #myforminput1 to have focus until after it scrolls to page three.  What happens when I add it to the code is that the page jumps to the focused element, and then animates to move the amount to page 3 so it overshoots the form. It might work if I could set the focus after the animation stops.

There is a similar problem with IE7 in that when a select box is selected using tabs, the page scrolls so that the select box is on the left part of a page.  It seems like this problem might be related.

Comment: JQuery's animate functions allow you to specify a callback. So, set the focus in the callback.

Comment: Could you not fire the focus() event after the animation has completed? Some code samples would be helpful too.

Comment: @Colin:  correct, it is working now. Did you see the second part of the question with IE7?  Any ideas on that?

Comment: Hard to tell what the issue is. Got any code you can show us?